# Reactive Extensions (Rx) Misses event

Tags: c#, events, scheduling, system.reactive

Why does a rx observing an event missed? The event is not handled at the time it occurs so the inner state of the object is not updated and causes problems in the following events received.
Can it be due to ObserveOn NewThread?

```
private void UpdateList(Client client)
{
    var listUpdateReceive = Observable
        .FromEvent<ListEventArgs>(ev => client.ListUpdateReceive += ev, ev => client.ListUpdateReceive -= ev);

    listUpdateReceive.Take(1)
        .Subscribe(r =>
                       {
                           TraceInformation("List is updated.");

                           OnListUpdateReceived(r.Sender, r.EventArgs);
                       });
}
```

I can see the event is received but the code above is blocking!

Comment: You'll need to give a working code example so that people can help you.

Comment: It completely depends on the code you've written. Supplying a code example will improve the quality of the question and allow others to see where you may have gone wrong. At the moment your question is too vague and you're unlikely to get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code sample looks fine to me, although the use of the `Take(1)` operator will result in only ever catching the first event at which point the stream will complete and you will not receive any additional notifications. Is it your intention to only listen for a single event notification?

Perhaps removing Take(1) will give you the correct behaviour?

```
private void UpdateList(Client client)
{
    var listUpdateReceive = Observable
        .FromEvent<ListEventArgs>(ev => client.ListUpdateReceive += ev, ev => client.ListUpdateReceive -= ev);

    listUpdateReceive.Subscribe(r =>
        {
           TraceInformation("List is updated.");

           OnListUpdateReceived(r.Sender, r.EventArgs);
        });
}
```

Comment: The issue is resolved. The blocking was due to non synchronized (absence of lock'ing) string modification.